# Select the first and last event per year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset with a bunch of event data. Some years have one event some have multiple.

I'm trying to only give the first and last event for a particular year.

This is what I have so far:

```
WITH yearnum (EID, ED, YR, EN, EDS, CID, COD) AS 
(
    SELECT
        eventid, MIN(eventdate) AS minimum_event_date,
        DATEPART(year, EVENTdate) AS year_in_question,
        EventName, EventDetails, CategoryID, CountryID
    FROM
        tblevent 
    GROUP BY
        eventid, EventDate, EventName, EventDetails, CategoryID, CountryID
),
rownumS (EID, ED, YR, EN, EDS, CID, COD, RN) AS
(
    SELECT
        EID, ED, YR, EN, EDS, CID, COD, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YR ORDER BY YR ASC) AS rownumyear
    FROM
        yearnum
)
SELECT 
    EID, ED, YR, EN, EDS, CID, COD, RN 
FROM 
    rownums
```

Result:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvPUM.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I can tell you for a start that if you want min and max events by year you shouldn't be grouping by all of those columns (and certainly not by date). You'll also want to explain what to do in edge cases, e.g. what if there are _two_ events on the same day, and that was the first or last date of an event in that year?

Comment: Apologies, I'm a noob at this. What I'm trying to achieve is lets say there were 3 events for 1976. 1 in Feb, 1 in June and 1 in Dec. I only want to select the event in Feb becuase that was the first event and the one in Dec because that was the last event

Comment: And what if there were two events on February 1st?

Comment: The test data is bogus. can I paste it here?

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying. Let me rephrase' I want the first and last event for each year per event ID?

Comment: You can create a [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle).

Comment: What is the PK of tblEvents?    It seems like the same event could occur multiple times in a year given your problem description; so I'm assuming EventID and EventDate are a combined key.

Comment: `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the problem down into pieces you can process.

- get a list of events with min date per year/id.
- get a list of events with max date per year/id.
- union list for inclusion.
- Select from from base set only those in our include list.

This may not be the most efficient way alternatives include

- Use Row_nubmer to get min/max then exlcude (example provided)
- use table value function cross apply to get min/max per year & event (Example NOT provided)

Assumptions:

- The PK for tblEvents is the EventID and EventDate
- EventID alone isn't unique and expect it to be repeated as an event could occur on different dates...
- SQL Below Untested due to lack of sample data.

Option 1) using exists and correlation to only incldue those with a min/max event date per year which we determine in advance in a common table expression.

```
WITH IncludeSet as (  --Get the list of records we want to incldue.
  SELECT min(EventDate) EventDate, EventID, Year(EventDate) EventYear
  FROM tblEvent
  GROUP BY EventID,Year(EventDate) 

  UNION -- We don't need union all becuase if an event only occurs once in  
        -- a year, we only need to see that event date once. union does a 
        -- distinct union all wouldn't. 

 SELECT max(EventDate) EventDate, EventID, Year(EventDate) EventYear
  FROM tblEvent
  GROUP BY EventID,Year(EventDate)
)

SELECT E.*  --only pull in the columns you need
FROM tblEvent E
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM IncludeSet InS. 
              where E.EventID = InS.EventID
                and E.EventDate = InS.EventDate)
```

Alternative apporach using rownumber window function...

- I use the Sub Commmon table expression to getnerate the row_numbers for the eventID, and year to ensure we can identify the min/max event of each year.
- note the only real difference on the rownumbers is the order by.

.

```
With Sub as (
SELECT E.*
   , Row_number() over (partition by Year(eventDate), EventID Order by EventDate Desc) as maxRN
   , Row_number() over (partition by Year(eventDate), EventID Order by EventDate ASC) as MinRN
FROM tblEvent)

SELECT Sub.* 
FROM Sub 
WHERE (maxRN=1 or MinRN=1)
```

- Depending on indexes on the table, table record size, and other factors one may be "better" than the other in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to display what I wanted:

```sql
drop table if exist #resultset

drop table if exists #row

with yearnum (EID,ED,YR,EN,EDS,CID,COD) 
AS 
(Select eventid,
min(eventdate) as minimum_event_date,
datepart(year,Eventdate) as year_in_question,
EventName,EventDetails,CategoryID,CountryID
from tblevent
group by eventid,EventDate,EventName,EventDetails,CategoryID,CountryID),

rownumS (EID,ED,YR,EN,EDS,CID,COD,RN) AS
(select EID,ED,YR,EN,EDS,CID,COD, row_number() over (partition by YR order by YR asc) as rownumyear
from yearnum)

select EID,ED,YR,EN,EDS,CID,COD,RN into #resultset from rownums;

select YR, MIN(ED),MAX(ED),MAX(RN) FROM #resultset
Group by YR
order by yr asc
```

Comment: Got a lot of flack from my mentor for my untidy query but will do better next time. We live and we learn

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: If you toss up some sample data, we can get this much cleaner